# android + scala + preinstalled scala libraries + disabled proguard throws ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, scala, classnotfoundexception, rooted-device

Final purpose of this feat: Use android device for development by fast compiling without needing to use proguard each single time (which causes huge delays)

First try is on **Sony Ericsson Xperia Mini Pro**

I have installed in it **Cyanogenmod** which is already **rooted** and the root checker app has verified it.

This is the app I used to **embed Scala library** 2.9.1 inside android device:
https://github.com/jbrechtel/Android-Scala-Installer
The lines `uses-library android:name="scala_...` are now included inside the AndroidManifest

After the above actions I did some minor changes inside **"project/Build.scala"** like this line: `useProguard in Android := false,`

I am probably missing something because after recompiling and executing `android:start-device` I got **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException**
which is the error you are expecting to get when you have not done the previous steps (rooting device and installing scala libraries inside device)

Any ideas are welcome! Thank you

PS: *Intellij is the chosen IDE for the current project so eclipse and the relative plugins is not an option*

Comment: I might be way of here, but did you use Proguard on the embedded scala library? If so did it strip that lib of it's content?

Comment: Which class is not found?

Comment: @EmilH Yes I was using proguard as everyone else who uses jberkel's android plugin and it is working fine like that and yes I guess the poing was to shrink the scala library in its minimum for current project in order to keep the size of the .apk file sane. Let me know if you need any more info

Comment: @RexKerr the class not found is MainActivity (obviously is the first activity being launched as set in the android manifest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with what I have mentioned above!

BUT there is a command inside Android Scala Installer which requests the "/system" folder to be mounted as writable. Unfortunately this does not work on my gingerbread android phone and this might be the general case.

I simply commented out the operation of the mount /system as writable (and also the command mount /system as read only) and the libraries installed successfully!
*Note that I set manually the permissions of /system as writable before installing libraries*

In fact I forked the github repository and therefore you can find me implementation over here:
https://github.com/pligor/scala-android-libs

To summarize. Yes the only alterations needed in your scala android source code is to set the settings in Build.scala file for proguard to be false and you include the uses `<uses-library android:name="scala_...` inside Android Manifest.